Why is Yarn trying to install 1.0.0 of a package when my package.json references ^0.22.0?
Here's my package.json:
{
  "scripts": {
    "examples": "docusaurus-examples",
    "start": "docusaurus-start",
    "build": "docusaurus-build",
    "publish-gh-pages": "docusaurus-publish",
    "write-translations": "docusaurus-write-translations",
    "version": "docusaurus-version",
    "rename-version": "docusaurus-rename-version"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "docusaurus": "^1.14.7",
    "cheerio": "^0.22.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react-treebeard": "^3.2.4"
  }
}

When I do yarn install I get this error:
error cheerio@1.0.0: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version ">=18.17". Got "16.20.2"
error Found incompatible module.

That makes sense - I'm running Node.js 16.20.2 and per the release notes Cheerio 1.0.0 was released a few day ago and bumped the minimum required version Node.js.
Ideally, I'd upgrade the version of Node.js that I'm running, but I got errors when I did that and then did yarn build.
But why is yarn install trying to install Cheerio 1.0.0 when I'm clearly telling it to install 0.22.0? I tried ^0.22.0, ~0.22.0 and 0.22.0.
Maybe one of Docusaurus's dependencies is requiring Cheerio 1.0.0 but, if that were the case, then shouldn't I be getting some sort of "incompatible requirements" error instead of what I am getting?

What does why say?

@jonrsharpe - See https://pastebin.com/AyEjpThd . I see cheerio ^1.0.0-rc.12 required in truncate-html 1.1.0's package.json whereas truncate-html 1.0.4's package.json requires 0.22.0 so I added "truncate-html": "1.0.4" to my own package.json. Upon doing that I now get https://pastebin.com/Mt0piJRV , which doesn't make any sense to me. Both times it mentions enzyme#cheerio@1.0.0 but the most recent version's package.json requires cheerio ^0.22.0 so how is it getting 1.0.0?

Not sure where you're looking but Enzyme has required Cheerio 1 (rc) since v3.0.0 https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/CHANGELOG.html#300

@jonrsharpe - I just clicked on the tags on https://github.com/enzymejs/enzyme but now that you mention that I see that they changed their tagging convention. They have a tag for v2.9.1 and then a tag for enzyme@3.0.0. Regardless, I added "enzyme": "2.9.1" to my package.json and, still, cheerio 1.0.0 is required. See https://pastebin.com/9RTG7JWB . Here's my current packcage.json: https://pastebin.com/zgXiNJ4D

Like at this point yarn why cheerio is now saying Found "docusaurus#cheerio@1.0.0" but if I do Ctrl + F in https://github.com/facebook/docusaurus/blob/v1.14.7/package.json I don't see "cheerio" at all, from which I conclude that cheerio is not a direct dependency of docusaurus.

It seems there's a lot you don't get about dependencies. Adding direct dependencies doesn't change your transitive dependencies - directly installing Enzyme 2 doesn't mean your own dependencies don't need and install Enzyme 3, for example, just that you now have (at least) two versions in the tree. You could look into explicit resolutions, but then things will likely start to break (because forcing a transitive dependency to the wrong major version will probably hit the same API changes that caused the increment to start with).

@jonrsharpe - yarn why cheerio seems to be of limited usefulness, then. If cheerio is being required by a dependency of docusaurus or a dependency of a dependency then maybe yarn why cheerio ought to say that. Like "cheerio@1.0.0 is required because of package x, which is required by package y, which is required by package z" but I guess that's too much to ask!  Might as well just ask someone to hand examine each of the ~800 new folders that that docusaurus adds to node_modules for as useful as yarn why cheerio is..

in packages.json file add this in your existing resolution and devDependencies
 "resolutions":{
    "cheerio": "<1.0.0"
}
and--
 "devDependencies":{
    "cheerio": "<1.0.0"
}

